# Bluetooth mouse not connecting to laptop?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have a Microsoft Wireless Notebook Presenter Mouse 8000 that has Bluetooth connectivity. I have tried to connect it directly to the computer's bluetooth without using the dongole, but it does not see the mouse. It connects to my Mac perfectly fine. Thanks!

Additional info: In the System settings on start up, Bluetooth is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  But I do this:

Open a terminal and run the following

`sudo apt-get install bluez-utils`

and restart bluetooth service

`sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`

Now if you run `lsusb` it will detect and list your Microsoft presenter 8000 mouse

Comment: I get an error saying

Comment: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"
I also tried logging in as root-still didn

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the relevant compatibility is installed via synaptic/Ubuntu software.

Theres no reason why it shouldnt work, unless its not a standard bluetooth HID. You might need to install specific compatibility, try searching the software by your device class and or name.