# Ubuntu 13.10 and Microsoft Wireless Notebook presenter 8000

Tags: 13.10, mouse, bluetooth, microsoft

I've tried pairing my mouse Microsoft Wireless Notebook presenter 8000 on my HP pavilion dv9000 laptop but I just can't hit "pair" button! (it is actually a "continue" button)

I've tried this suggestion: [Getting Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse working with Ubuntu 8.10](http://blog.chinthaka.org/2008/09/getting-microsoft-bluetooth-mouse.html)

and also this one: [Bluetooth mouse not connecting to laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221510/bluetooth-mouse-not-connecting-to-laptop)

But none seem to fix the issue.

In detail:

- I set my mouse in pairing mode (light at bottom flashes green and
  red)
- I open up bluetoooth utility and ask it to pair with a new
  device
- tool searches for devices
- It finds microsoft presenter mouse and displays it's mac address.
- No matter how long I wait the tool will never display the name of the
  mouse. Just it's mac address, whereas for other devices seconds after
  it detects them the mac address is replaced by the device name.
- the continue button remains greyed out even when I select the mouse
  on the list of devices to be paired. I cannot do anything from that
  point on. I just have to close the bluetooth program.

Note that I can connect perfectly well on other devices, and the mouse works flawlessly on windows 8 on the same computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would like to see an answer to this question as well, so even though it's four years old, if anyone knows anything, it's still worth answering this question.  Thanks.